# how to fix this error void dda_algorithm(int,int,int,int)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'double (__cdecl *)(double)' to 'int'?

Tags: visual-c++

I wrote this code which make line using DDA line drawing algorithm but always end up getting error i don't know why, although i passed argument as a int please help me with this.... i tried but i not getting what the acutall error is please if anyone could find.

```
include<GL/glut.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int x1, x2, y1, y2;
void dda_algorithm(int x1,int x2,int y1,int y2){

    int  dx = abs(x2 - x1);

    int dy = abs(y2 - y1);
    
    int steps = (abs(dx) > abs(dy)) ? abs(dx) : abs(dy);


    float increment_in_x = dx / (float)steps;
    float increment_in_y = dy / (float)steps;

    float x = (float)x1;
    float y = (float)y1;


    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        glVertex2i(x, y);

        x += increment_in_x;
        y += increment_in_y;
    }
}
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    dda_algorithm(x1,x2,y1,y2);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

}



void init() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0,400,0,400);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "enter the x1 and x2  variables of two points:->" << endl;
    cin >> x1 >> x2;
    cout << "enter the y1 and y2 variables of two points:-->" << endl;
    cin >> y1 >> y2;
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("DDA Line Drawing Algo");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: My guess is that, somewhere in the code not shown, you have a function named `y1`

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the Visual Studio header `math.h` defines the function `y1` (a Bessel function, I guess). You can suppress it by defining the macro `_CRT_DECLARE_NONSTDC_NAMES` as `0` in your project. It's not clear to me why this function is picked up though; the global variable `int y1` should have hidden it.

Comment: Ah. When I try your example, I get another error, earlier, on the `int x1, x2, y1, y2;` line: "error C2365: 'y1': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'". Always resolve errors from the top down, and always cite all the errors you see when asking a question here; prepare a [mcve]. Anyway, to resolve the immediate issue, either use the `_CRT_DECLARE_NONSTDC_NAMES` trick I mentioned earlier, or avoid naming your global variable `y1` (better still, avoid global variables altogether).